# "Error locating server" - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, tcp, sql-server-2014

I have a problem trying to connect to a SQL Server.
I tried using IP address or name of the server on my connection string but I still get an "Error Locating Server".
I enabled TCP/IP on the server and restart it, but no good results.

My actual connection string is : `Server=POSTESERVEUR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=false;Database=****;User ID=****;Password=****;`

The error is :

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider:SQL Network Interfaces, error:26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

I have always read a lot of answers to similar problems, but I still don't get what I'm doing wrong.

The SQL Service is running, TCP/IP is listening, and I can ping the server via CMD, the user ID works too, so what is wrong ?

All ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Please paste entire error

Comment: I edit my post @TheGameiswar

Answer (score 1):

You need to check some steps.

1. Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
2. Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application converts \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please try both ServerInstance and Server\Instance in your connection string]
3. Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
4. Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.
5. If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.
6. Make sure the Remote Connections enabled on SQL Server – Ensure SQL Server is allowed for remote connections(Server properties/connection/allow remote connection to this server)

Comment: I follow every step, but it still don't work, I'm disapointed.

Comment: @BlackAlpha It sounds a little a bit strange. If you have Team Viewer, I can connect to you and check the issue on your PC. If so, please email me your Team Viewer Username and Password. farahmandian2011[at]gmail.com